# Combo bar chart graph line gets obscured by bars

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a combined bar chart and line graph using chart js:

```
new Chart(ctx { ... }
```

I found this [sample on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TvY5tz?p=preview) of a combined bar chart and line graph. The line graph appears drawn on top of the bar chart which is the way I want it.

However I copied the sample into [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3cwqnb7f/1/) and for some reason the bars are drawn over the line.

Is there a way I can explicitly ensure the line graph appears on top of the bar chart?

Answer (score 0):

I have realised it goes according to the order in which you define them. When you define the line graph first then it appears above the bar chart. You can see this in my updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56dmqg8h/)

```
datasets: [{
                label: "Sales",
                    type:'line',
                    data: [51, 65, 40, 49, 60, 37, 40],
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#EC932F',
                    backgroundColor: '#EC932F',
                    pointBorderColor: '#EC932F',
                    pointBackgroundColor: '#EC932F',
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#EC932F',
                    pointHoverBorderColor: '#EC932F',
                    yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                  label: "Visitor",
                    data: [200, 185, 590, 621, 250, 400, 95],
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: '#71B37C',
                    borderColor: '#71B37C',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
                    hoverBorderColor: '#71B37C',
                    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
            } ]
```

However, this doesn't explain why the original Plunker example doesn't have this issue